# fontspec+polyglossia... lack of spaces before punctuation marks (French) in standalone and dinbrief

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, dinbrief

I fail to get Lualatex to properly typeset punctuation marks for French when using the classes standalone or dinbrief. In this minimal example I would expect to see spaces before the colon and before the exclamation mark. Altering the document class to article I do get the expected behavior.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec, polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
   \today{} here: should have been a space before those two dots!
\end{document}
```

[image]

How could I enforce these spaces? I'm less worried about standalone, but given the issue in dinbrief and possibly a number of other document classes this would be nice to be able to do.

Thanks for your hints.

Bastian

Comment: And a small space before the `!` !

Comment: Bug in `standalone`, I'd say.

Comment: If I change `standalone` into `dinbrief`, I get the spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho it is a problem of the implementation in polyglossia: the space is lost inside some boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{l}
   \today{} here: should have been a space before those two dots!
   \end{tabular}

   \mbox{\today{} here: should have been a space before those two dots!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably you are using it in dinbrief in a place where such boxes are involved.